# ajax reload for datatable not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have been trying to reload jQuery Datatables for every 10 seconds, but I get an issue as mentioned below.

Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table1=$('.MessagingTable').DataTable({
    }); 

    setInterval(
        function(){
            table1.api().ajax.reload(); 
        }, 
        10000 
    ); 
});
```

It throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'api'

Comment: You sure it is not `.dataTable()` instead of `.DataTable()`. But of course if not just a typo in question, you'd get other error in console, right?!

Comment: It is DataTable i am using and in console i just get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'api' " Error for every minute for the interval time i had set

Comment: Ya you are correct if you are talking about jquery datatable plugin. Now depending which version you are using, it could be just: `table1.ajax.reload();`   https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: i even tried that , but it throws "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reload' of undefined" in console

Comment: And if you do `console.log(table1);`, what do you get? And please provide relevant link to datatable plugin/version you are using, i'm not sure which one it is

Comment: i get for console.log(table1); as table====[object Object] and i am using jquery.dataTables.min.js i am using its 1.9 version

Comment: And which option are you passing to datatable when initialize it? In your posted code , no ajax option is passed

Comment: i was using the option in data table as ajax: "data.json"

Comment: @wolff is there anything i am missing in this code?

Comment: Please post your DataTables initialization options

Comment: var table2=$('.MessagingTable').DataTable({
                      ajax:'<%=response.encodeURL(bannerAckUrl.toString())%>', }); setInterval( function () {
                console.log("table===="+table1);
                   table1.ajax.reload();}, 10000 ); 
           
              });

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

Correct way to reload the table with data retrieved via Ajax is to use 
[`ajax.reload()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29) API method as shown below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu'
});

setInterval(
    function(){
        table.ajax.reload(); 
    }, 
    10000
);
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m42nmg5a/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: could you please tell me how to form this ajax: URL as shown above in my case i had created simple datatable that fetches the data from the server side(say java bean value) everytime the page gets loaded and  i need to refresh the datatable only that will fetch the data from the server side every minute